# Как выбрать одно значение из Json Array

Tags: java, json

Преобразовал **Json String** в **Java объект** с помощью *objectMapper*. Теперь из массива Json не могу получить значение для **Cod** или **dtBeg**. *deserialize.getAlgorithms* выводит массив.

вот JSON

```
{
"status": 1,
"message": "ok",
"sheduleCod": "NOST_A_Persons_m_noaccum",
"algorithms": [{
    "cod": "No_st_alg_1",
    "kcp": "U6000427",
    "dtBeg": "2017-11-01 00:00:00",
    "dtEnd": "2017-12-01 00:00:00"
}, {
    "cod": "No_st_alg_2",
    "kcp": "U6000427",
    "dtBeg": "2017-11-01 00:00:00",
    "dtEnd": "2017-12-01 00:00:00"
}, {
    "cod": "No_st_alg_3",
    "kcp": "U6000427",
    "dtBeg": "2017-11-01 00:00:00",
    "dtEnd": "2017-12-01 00:00:00"
}]
```

}

Main.Class

```
JsonDeserialize deserialize = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, JsonDeserialize.class);
System.out.println(deserialize.getAlgorithms)
```

Comment: `System.out.println(deserialize.getAlgorithms[0].getCod)`

Comment: ошибка в getAlgortihms.@Igor

Comment: algorithms у вас массив. вам нужно его перебрать или дергать по индексу.

Comment: @Сергей верно, но вот я не знаю как перебрать все значения Cod в массиве

Comment: Я щас не за компом проверить не могу. А что если for (int i = 0; i < deserialize.getAlgorithms.lenght; i++) {//что-то делаем...}

Comment: @Сергей я так пробовал, выводит ошибку в _length_. Мне интересно как можно deserialize.getAlgorithms преобразовать в массив List или ArrayList и уже дальше выводить

Comment: List<?> list = Arrays.asList(deserialize.getAlgorithms) ? Ну или что-то вроде. А вобще зачем это? Если можно использовать библиотеку org-json и  средства JSONObject с JSONArray

Answer (score 1):

Без сериализаторов(используя org-json):

```
String jsonString = "{}";
try {
    JSONObject response = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    JSONArray algorithms = response.getJSONArray("algorithms");
    for (int i = 0; i < algorithms.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject j = algorithms.getJSONObject(i);
        String cod = j.getString("cod");
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: это работает! спасибо. но причина в том что я использую сериализацию,потому что  я дальше буду сравнивать эти значения с другими значениями, в этом случае неудобно получается.

Comment: если у вас всегда одинаковый набор ключей, тоесть структура json, то можно создать четкий класс и получится как сериализация только более понятна.

Comment: у меня есть четкий класс с геттерами и сеттерами для целого объекта _json_ и отдельный класс для _algorithms_. **Сериялизация** понятно, только вот дергать оттуда значения никак не получается. Эти значения нужны мне чтобы сравнивать их с базой данных. Вот такая вот проблема

Comment: тогда я не совсем понял как вы сравниваете и что именно

Comment: в массиве **algorithms** беру _cod(их три в массиве)_ и сравниваю их с _String cod="No_st_alg_2"_ и именно его dtBeg беру для загрузки в бд